# Should you create one DTO for the params, one for the body, one for the queries, ...?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dto

So let's assume you have an API endpoint that takes

- 1 to *n* parameters
- 1 to *n* body values
- 1 to *n* queries

you want to create a DTO to fetch and validate all those values. As you might know it's not possible to have one DTO class for the whole request, so this doesn't work:

```
public class Dto
{
    [FromRoute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The parser will only set the `Foo` field and ignore the `Id` field. When calling https://localhost:5001/foo/1 the `Id` field will just have its default value 0, not 1. It is possible to create one DTO for the url params, one for the body and one for the queries like so

```
public class ParamsDto
{
    public int FirstId { get; set; }
    public int SecondId { get; set; }
}

// ... same for the body and queries ...
```

and then you can tag those dtos like so `[FromRoute] ParamsDto paramsDto, [FromBody] BodyDto bodyDto, [FromQuery] QueryDto queryDto`. You might have a multilayer architecture and your Web API project communicates with a layer that expects a DTO which is a combination of all 3 DTOs shown above. So you have to merge those 3 objects to one big DTO e.g. converting the request DTOs to a command object (from **Mediatr**) with **AutoMapper**..

Are there any best practises to deal with multiple DTOs in terms of folder structure, naming convention, .. ? Because instead of having a DTO called `UpdateProductAmountFromOrderByIds` which takes the `orderId`, `productId` and the `amount` (of products) you might have to create one DTO for the params `UpdateProductAmountFromOrderByIdsParamsDto` and one for the body `UpdateProductAmountFromOrderByIdsBodyDto`. I know this is not the best example because DTOs are not really needed here but let's assume you would have a complex validation for the IDs and the body contains more than one value. You don't want to have that many validation annotations in your controller file. In terms of merging those separate DTOs to one big this approach looks really messy to me so maybe there are better approaches.

Comment: Why would you need one for queries? Look up the odata specs - quite explicity on how to define an API that is so vastly suprerior to 99.9% of the stuff people propose that it is not funny. The backend is QUITE non trivial, but the benefit is - interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo for asp.net core 3.0:

Model:

```
public class Dto
{
    [FromRoute(Name = "")]
    public Test Test { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public Sample Sample { get; set; }
    public ApiVersion ApiVersion { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
    public bool Col3 { get; set; }
}
public class ApiVersion
{
    public int VersionId { get; set; }
    public string VersionName { get; set; }
}
public class Sample
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet("col1/{col1}/col2/{col2}/col3/{col3}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]Dto dto)
    {           
        return Ok(dto);
    }
}
```

Request url:`https://localhost:44393/api/values/col1/1/col2/2/col3/true?apiversion.versionId=1&apiversion.versionName=aaa`

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

```
public class Dto
{
    //[FromRoute(Name = "")]
    //public Test Test { get; set; }
    [FromRoute]
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    [FromRoute]
    public int Col2 { get; set; }
    [FromRoute]
    public bool Col3 { get; set; }
    [FromBody]
    public Sample Sample { get; set; }
    public ApiVersion ApiVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. would you mind explaining `(Name = "")` and does the annoation in the controller matter (`[FromQuery]`)? And do you have to put the route IDs into another object?

Comment: Because you add the FromRoute to the nested model,you need define `Name=""` to ignore the parent model's name,then the model binding system could identify your nested model's property.The FromQuery must be add in the action.You could design by yourself,if you do not want to put route to another object,you could check my new model which is also well.If my answer help you,could you accept as answer?